# Ruby: Discovering constants and variables in objects

Tags: ruby, singleton, metadata

I have the following constant and instance variable in this object:

```
MyObj = Object.new
class << MyObj
  MY_CONST      = 'FindMe'
  @my_var       = 'OrMe'
  # ...
end
```

Is there any way to automatically discover these items, either inside or
outside the object?  Unfortunately, I'm currently using Ruby 1.8.6 and 1.9.3, but I also have access to 2.1.3 to test any solutions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have everything declared on eigenclass, you should lookup eigenclass for newly defined constant and var:

```
▶ MyObj.singleton_class.constants
#⇒ [
#  [0] :MY_CONST
# ]
▶ MyObj.singleton_class.instance_variables
#⇒ [
#  [0] :@my_var
# ]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nope. Sorry for that.